# Adding overlay to custom UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, video, swift2, uiimagepickercontroller

I have extended the UIImagePickerController, but I am not sure the how to have my custom overlay displayed. The one presented in the storyboard appears to be ignored and the adding it as a separate view doesn't seem to help either. I am wondering whether I am doing this in the right part of the lifecycle or whether there is an additional attribute I need to set?

```
class VideoRecorderViewController: UIImagePickerController {
    var overlayView : UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        self.sourceType = .Camera
        self.cameraCaptureMode = .Video

        self.allowsEditing = false
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.showsCameraControls = false
        self.overlayView = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("RecorderOverlayView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView)

        if (self.overlayView != nil) {

            self.overlayView?.frame = self.cameraOverlayView!.frame
            self.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;            
        } 
    }    
}
```

Other examples, which do work, have the UIImagePickerController created from another UIView, but I would rather avoid an otherwise empty UIView for simply creating the UIImagePickerController.

Using Swift 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [UIImagePickerController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/):

> IMPORTANT
>
> The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This
> class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.
> The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified,
> with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the
> cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional
> information or manage the interactions between the camera interface
> and your code.

You are attempting to subclass UIImagePickerController. You should create a view with the custom UI you want for video capture then set the instance of UIImagePickerController instance's overlayView. That view can have subview's that are controls that target the UIImagePickerController's presentingViewController.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I want the view the camera to automatically start on the views appearance, should I place presentViewController() in the viewDidAppear() function, or is there a better place for this?

Comment: In `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` You can say something like `self.presentViewController(imagePickerController,animated:true,completion:({imagePickerController.startVideoCapture()})` Not sure if that will work if you don't have camera permissions. Generally considered better UX to allow user to start recording.